# Capturing a repeating group

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to write a regex that would match and capture the following for me ...

String: 17+18+19+5+21

Numbers to be captured here (separately) are present in the array - [17,18,21].

Please note that the string can be n character long (following the same pattern of \d+) and the order of these numbers in the string are not fixed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language / regex engine?

Comment: So you're trying to ignore every multiple of 3rd and 4th element or every occurrence of 19 or 5?

Comment: ignore every occurrence of number except the one's in the array ...

Comment: I am using a perl regex engine so PCRE syntax

Comment: How about simply, `m/(17|18|21)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

```
(17|18|21)
```

It needs to be a global match, so in Pearl it would be like this:

```
$string =~ m/(17|18|21)/g
```

Example string:

```
21+18+19+5+21+18+19+17
```

Matches:

```
"21", "18", "21", "18", "17"
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/jL8iF7

Comment: Thanks for the solution .. works fine :) i was just ignoring the global match (duh)

Answer (score 2):

Given this setup:

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- "17+18+19+5+21"
a <- c(17, 18, 21)
```

**1)** Try this:

```
L <- as.list(c(setNames(a, a), NA))
strapply(s, "\\d+", L, simplify = na.omit)
```

giving:

```
[1] 17 18 21
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3 4
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

**2)** or this:

```
pat <- paste(a, collapse = "|")
strapplyc(s, pat, simplify = as.numeric)
```

giving:

```
[1] 17 18 21
```

**3)** or this non-regexp solution

```
intersect(scan(text = s, what = 0, sep = "+", quiet = TRUE), a)
```

giving

```
[1] 17 18 21
```

*ADDED* additional solution.

Comment: +1 FYI scan takes a `text` argument, making the call to `textConnection` unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. Have now incorporated that.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
vec <- "17+18+19+5+21"
a <- c(17, 18, 21) 

pattern <- paste0("\\b(", paste(a, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
# [1] "\\b(17|18|21)\\b"

regmatches(vec, gregexpr(pattern, vec))[[1]]
# [1] "17" "18" "21"
```

Note that this matches the exact number, i.e., `17` does not match `177`.